# Spring transaction doesn't rollback when checked exception is thrown

Tags: spring, exception, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm trying to execute sample of transaction code. I throw checked exception from transactional method and set rollbackFor parameter for the class of this exception. However this transaction doesn't rollback. So my question is what may be the reason of that behaviour. Here is a sample of my code:

MyService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyService implements IMyService {

    @Autowired
    private IMyDao myDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = BreakException.class)
    public void test() throws BreakException {
        myDao.updateMethodA("64", "'N'", "'2015.01.01/0008661/0008'");
        if(true) throw new BreakException();
        myDao.updateMethodB("15", "'N'", "'2015.01.01/0008661/0008'");
    }
}
```

MyDao:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao implements IMyDao {

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void updateOperationA(String x, String y, String z) {
        String sql = "UPDATE ...."; //masked for example
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void updateOperationB(String saldoPo, String saldo_status, String unikalne_id) throws BreakException {
        String sql = "UPDATE ...."; //masked for example
        //if(true) throw new BreakException();
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }
}
```

1.) So when I call test() on MyService the update from method updateMethodA is not rolledback after BreakException() is thrown.

2.) BreakException is my class that extends Exception

3.) When I throw BreakException from updateOperationB(commented in example) it does rollback correctly.

4.) When I change BreakException to extend TransactionException it works as expected so it seems the problem is only when I extend Exception.